# JavaScript code does not execute, although the "else if" condition is fulfilled

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a HTML page with some JavaScript, and I'm meeting with a problem.

I need that when a input is changed, it checks if its value is greater or equals to another input's value, but I can't find it working, although I use the same exact code for that other input (and it's working), but with changing the variables.

```js
function changeGlobalMaxClients() {
    var maxClients = document.getElementById("wlMaxClients").value;
    var globalMaxClients = document.getElementById("wlGlobalMaxClients").value;

    if (globalMaxClients.length == "0" || globalMaxClients == "0") {
        alert("Global Max Clients setting cannot be disabled.");
        location.reload();
    } else if (maxClients >= globalMaxClients) {
        alert("Global Max Clients value cannot be less nor equal to Max Clients setting.");
        location.reload();
    };
};

function changeMaxClients() {
    var maxClients = document.getElementById("wlMaxClients").value;
    var globalMaxClients = document.getElementById("wlGlobalMaxClients").value;

    if (maxClients.length == "0" || maxClients == "0") {
        alert("Max Clients setting cannot be disabled.");
        location.reload();
    } else if (maxClients >= globalMaxClients) {
        alert("Max Clients value cannot be greater nor equal to Global Max Clients setting.");
        location.reload();
    };
};
```

```html
<!-- Global Max Clients -->
        <p>Global Max Clients:&emsp;
            <input type="text" name="wlGlobalMaxClients" id="wlGlobalMaxClients" maxlength="3" size="1" value="64" onchange="changeGlobalMaxClients()">&emsp;
            <span class="small">Note: this setting cannot be less nor equal to the value of Max Clients setting.</span>
        </p>
        <br>
        <!-- END Global Max Clients -->

<!-- Max Clients -->
        <p>Max Clients:&emsp;
            <input type="text" name="wlMaxClients" id="wlMaxClients" maxlength="3" size="1" value="32" onchange="changeMaxClients()">&emsp;
            <span class="small">Note: this setting cannot be greater nor equal to the value of Global Max Clients setting.</span>
        </p>
        <br>
        <!-- END Max Clients -->
```

If run the code and change the value of `globalMaxClients` to a value that is less or equals to `maxClients`, it shows up the alert and refreshes the page, but if I try to change the value of `maxClients` to a value that is greater or equals to `globalMaxClients`, it does not show up the alert nor it refreshes the page.

I tried to switch the `maxClients >= globalMaxClients` part to `globalMaxClients <= maxClients`, but it doesn't work.

If more information is needed, just reply to the post. Sorry if there's any grammatical error, I'm not too good with English.

**EDIT/UPDATE**: my problem is that if `maxClients` value is greater or equals to `globalMaxClients` value (or if `globalMaxClients` value is less or equals to `maxClients` value), it should show an alert and refresh the page, but I found out that if the value of any of the two variables is more than `100` (including `100`), the alert is not shown and it does not refresh the page. However, if the values are below `100`, the code does work.

**EDIT 2**: also, it seems that if I put a value higher than `100` on `globalMaxClients`, the code works, but at the contrary direction. The thing that happens is:

If I change the value of `globalMaxClients` to, for example, `112`, and the value of `maxClients` is below this number (let's say `10`), it shows the alert saying that `globalMaxClients` value cannot be less or equal to `maxClients`, but the thing is that `112 > 10`, so it should not show that alert.

Comment: 'Value' is a string, so you compare strings. Try:   var maxClients = parseInt(document.getElementById("wlMaxClients").value); etc

Comment: If you are going to compare values, remember that values gotten from HTML elements are strings. If you need them to be compared as numbers, convert them in place by prepending `+` to them. For example: `var maxClients = +document.getElementById("wlMaxClients").value;`

Comment: Your code is working in the snippet... I changed maxClients to 99 and I got an alert. Something somewhere else in your code must be causing the problem... you'll need to take a look and see if you missed anything in the code you included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it working.

The problem was, as stated by [Poul Bak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5741643/poul-bak), my code did not have `parseInt(document.getElementById("id-of-element").value)` on every `var`code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do. If you want to be able to test and change values the code below should work for you.  If you want to always set the values back to the defaults uncomment both loads

```js
var globalMaxClients = document.getElementById("wlGlobalMaxClients").value;
var maxClients = document.getElementById("wlMaxClients").value;




function changeGlobalMaxClients() {
    var maxClients = document.getElementById("wlMaxClients").value;
    var globalMaxClients = document.getElementById("wlGlobalMaxClients").value;
    
    console.log(globalMaxClients,maxClients);

    if (globalMaxClients.length == "0" || globalMaxClients == "0") {
        alert("Global Max Clients setting cannot be disabled.");
        //location.reload();
    } else if (maxClients >= globalMaxClients) {
        console.log('hello');
        alert("Global Max Clients value cannot be less nor equal to Max Clients setting.");
        //location.reload();
    };
    
    
};

function changeMaxClients() {
  console.log('in');
    var maxClients = document.getElementById("wlMaxClients").value;
    var globalMaxClients = document.getElementById("wlGlobalMaxClients").value;
   
   console.log(globalMaxClients,maxClients);

    if (maxClients.length == "0" || maxClients == "0") {
        alert("Max Clients setting cannot be disabled.");
        //location.reload();
    } else if (maxClients >= globalMaxClients) {
        alert("Max Clients value cannot be greater nor equal to Global Max Clients setting.");
        //location.reload();
    };
};
```

```html
<!-- Global Max Clients -->
        <p>Global Max Clients:&emsp;
            <input type="text" name="wlGlobalMaxClients" id="wlGlobalMaxClients" maxlength="3" size="1" value="64" onchange="changeGlobalMaxClients()">&emsp;
            <span class="small">Note: this setting cannot be less nor equal to the value of Max Clients setting.</span>
        </p>
        <br>
        <!-- END Global Max Clients -->

<!-- Max Clients -->
        <p>Max Clients:&emsp;
            <input type="text" name="wlMaxClients" id="wlMaxClients" maxlength="3" size="1" value="32" onchange="changeMaxClients()">&emsp;
            <span class="small">Note: this setting cannot be greater nor equal to the value of Global Max Clients setting.</span>
        </p>
        <br>
        <!-- END Max Clients -->
```

Comment: Hello, I have updated the post to reflect my goal.

Also, I have seen that if both values are below `100` (without including `100`), the code does work.